# Controlling robot makes a shaking movement

Tags: c, coordinates, robotics

Im trying to control a robot by sending positions with 100hz. It's making a shaking movement when sending so much positions. When I send 1 position that is like 50 mm from his start position it moves smoothly. When I use my sensor to steer,(so it send every position from 0 to 50mm) it is shaking. I'm probably sending like X0-X1-X2-X1-X2-X3-X4-X5-X4-X5 and this is the reason why it might shake. How can I solve this making the robot move smoothly when I use my mouse to steer it?

- Robot is asking 125hz
- IR sensor is sending 100hz
- Otherwise does the 25hz makes the diffrent?

Here is my code.

```
        while(true)
        // If sensor 1 is recording IR light.
        if (listen1.newdata = true)
        {

            coX1 = (int) listen1.get1X();           // 
            coY1 = (int) listen1.get1Y();       
            newdata = true;
        } else {
            coX1 = 450;
            coY1 = 300;
        }

        if (listen2.newdata = true)
        {       
            coX2 = (int) listen2.get1X();
            coY2 = (int) listen2.get1Y();
            newdata = true; 
        } else {
            coY2 = 150;
        }
        // If the sensor gets further then the workspace, it will automaticly correct it to these 
        // coordinates.

        if (newdata = true)
        {
            if (coX1< 200 || coX1> 680)
            {
                coX1 = 450;
            }
            if (coY1<200 || coY1> 680)
            {
                coY1 = 300;
            }
            if (coY2<80 || coY2> 300)
            {
                coY2 = 150;
            }
        }
        // This is the actually command send to a robot.
        Gcode = String.format( "movej(p[0.%d,-0.%d, 0.%d, -0.5121, -3.08, 0.0005])"+ "\n", coX1, coY1, coY2);

        //sends message to server
        send(Gcode, out);     
            System.out.println(Gcode);
            newdata = false;

        }


}


private static void send(String movel, PrintWriter out) {
     try {


         out.println(movel); /*Writes to server*/
        // System.out.println("Writing: "+ movel);
        // Thread.sleep(250);
         }

         catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.print("Error Connecting to Server\n");
         } 
        }
}
```

@ Edit

I discovered on wich way I can do this. It is via min and max. So basicly what I think I have to do is: 
 * put every individual coordinate in a array( 12 coordinates)
 * Get the min and max out of this array 
 * Output the average of the min and max

Comment: This question should be moved to http://robotics.stackexchange.com

Comment: thank you. Didnt know there was a forum like this specially for robots.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your robot characteristics and how you could control it, here are some general considerations:

To have a smooth motion of your robot, you should control it in speed with a well designed PID controller algorithm.

If you can only control it in position, the best you can do is monitoring the position & waiting for it to be "near enough" from the targetted position before sending the next position.

If you want a more detailed answer, please give more information on the command you send to the robot (`movej`), I suspect that you can do much more than just sending [x,y] coordinates.

Comment: The movej, movel or movep can have parameters like: pose (position XYZ), a (acceleration), v(velocity), t(time) and r (blend radius). For my concept I have to send these commands directly. Ive been trying some several things with sending these commands. As I thought it sended more then 100 commands every second it is just sending 2-3 commands per second. I think I might try a min max => average and only send the average of these min and max. Maybe it will get the unnessecary positions out of it.